# Extracting connection string from configuration manager

Tags: c#, database, connection-string

I have a problem. I am trying To extract a connection string through

```
sqlConnStr = new qlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PlacementConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

but it keeps failing :

> Object Ref not set to an instance of an object

I check with the debugger and this is the value of the `connectionStr`

```
{Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Placement.accdb}
```

I have imported my database through VS2012's DataSet wizard so what am I doing wrong?

PS: I have tested the connection numerous times.

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="_201103578_P09.Properties.Settings.PlacementConnectionString" 
        connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=|DataDirectory|\Placement.accdb"
        providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Kind regards

Markus

[UPDATE]

I changed from

```
sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

try
{
    sqlConnStr = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PlacementConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
}
```

to

```
sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
string s = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[1].ConnectionString;

try
{
    sqlConnStr = new SqlConnection(s);
}
```

I inspect s and the value is

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Placement.accdb
```

Now an error is thrown

> System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'provider'

At wits' end;

=================================================================

TO EVERYONE - THANK YOU the problem was (I forgot) when using an Access database you have to use `OleDbCommand` and not `SqlCommand`. Thank you everything works fine now! – Markus just now edit

Comment: plz post the past of config containing connection string

Comment: check that `PlacementConnectionString` is indeed the name of the ConnectionString

Comment: You're missing a letter in `new qlConnection`

Comment: What is connectionStr ? I don't see it in your code

Comment: connectionStr, the abbreviated "ConnectionString" which is a private variable of the ConfigurationManager's enumeration of all the ConnectionStrings

Comment: see @OnResolve's answer; the config value (`_201103578_P09.Properties.Settings.PlacementConnectionString`) should match the name by which you are trying to identify the connection string (`"PlacementConnectionString"`)

Comment: @w0lf - It does, again i copied it out of the Config File. Correct me if i misunderstand. And as i said it does return the connection string it is just something horrible happens - read the update
Ps it accepts both `"_201103578_P09.Properties.Settings.PlacementConnectionString"` and  'PlacementConnectionString" as the same ref, it's an alias according to MSDN

Comment: if you have `<add name="_201103578_P09.Properties.Settings.PlacementConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=|DataDirectory|\Placement.accdb"
        providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />` ...

Comment: ... then you should probably have `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["_201103578_P09.Properties.Settings.PlacementConnectionString"].ConnectionString` in your code

Comment: Tried that and i have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Going off the code you posted, the only explanation I can see is that the null reference you're getting is related to the configuration manager not getting anything by the string you're passing it.

if

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PlacementConnectionString"]
```

doesn't return anything-- calling

```
.ConnectionString
```

will fail with your error. Can you verify that

> "PlacementConnectionString"

is the correct name of the connection?

Answer (score 1):

Your connectionstring name is incorrect

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="_201103578_P09.Properties.Settings.PlacementConnectionString" 
    connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=|DataDirectory|\Placement.accdb"
    providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
```

Instead it should be

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="PlacementConnectionString" 
    connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=|DataDirectory|\Placement.accdb"
    providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
```

Or in your code you should look for

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["_201103578_P09.Properties.Settings.PlacementConnectionString"].ConnectionString
```